# How to add image to background of title page in Rmarkdown Presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm attempting to create a powerpoint in R using RMarkdown. Is there a way to add an image as a background in the title page (e.g [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png)) and a logo in the header of footer of each slide (e.g [this logo](https://logo-logos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/mercedes-benz_logo_png_small.png))?

Also, I'd like to adjust the header of each slide to the left side instead of having it in the center.

My YAML is as follows

```
---
title: "Presentation"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

## Slide 1

- Point 1
- Point 2
- Point 3

## Slide 2
```

Comment: you mean the whole first page would be covered in the pic you have given?

Comment: Hi @PesKchan, yes

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, and I do not have a good answer. But for quarto presentations, there is an easy fix.

```
---
title: "Presentation"
title-slide-attributes:
    data-background-image: images/title_background.jpg
    data-background-size: contain
    data-background-opacity: "0.6"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
format: 
  revealjs:
    hash-type: number
    transition: fade
    auto-stretch: false
    self-contained: true
    height: 900
    width: 1600
knitr: 
  opts_chunk: 
    echo: false
---

## Slide 1

- Point 1
- Point 2
- Point 3
    
## Slide 2
```

The result is acceptable too

[image: Title page]